# Flask Security Login Url

Tags: python, flask, authentication, flask-security

I am using Flask Security in my flask project to handle authentication.

Currently, navigating to example.com/login works perfectly.  However, example.com/login.html results in a template not found error.  I am assuming this is because flask-security is only handling the /login with nothing appended to it.

Right now I have gotten around this by adding a 
redirect that goes from /login.html to /login.

```
@app.route('/login.html', methods=['GET'])
def loginReRoute():
    return redirect('/login')
```

Is this the best way to account for this?  Or is there an easy way to get flask-security to directly handle the login URL with .html appended?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can you not just use login?

Comment: All the HTML files that I have been given have a mix of /login and /login.html.  I could just do a find and replace to get them all the same I suppose.

Comment: Personally, that's what I would do, that way you are not doing a mix-and-match type of thing.

Comment: Agreed! Ill go ahead and do that.

Comment: How your user access the `/login.html` in  the first place. Remove the code from your project. Just show the url that navigate to `/login`.